# how to tag panel link in panel body in css

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

the thing is that I have a panel with no head and the blog post inside just the body. I have successfully added the code to the body to affect the text decoration of the link, but cannot find the tag to do it in css alone.

```
<div class = "panel panel-default panel-body">
  <article class = "post">
    <h2><a href = "<?php the_permalink(); ?>" style="text-decoration: none"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </article>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance
Steven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some **CSS combinators**:

```
.post h2 a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

This will select all `a` tags inside `h2` tags that are childrens of an element with `post` class.